# Can the GCC linker emit an error when a specific symbol is included in the link?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'd like to forbid a set of specifically-named symbols from being linked into my executable, to ensure that my executable isn't carrying around functionality and dependencies that I don't want.

In my specific case, these symbols come from `libc_nano.a` on an ARM Cortex-M MCU, but I've wanted this functionality for application-level code as well on "bigger" computers as well, so my question is general-purpose.

I don't see a linker flag that would trigger an error if a named symbol is included in the final link, but I think that would do what I want.

Is there a way to achieve this with the GCC linker?

Comment: Let it emit a map file, then parse it. Or use `objdump` and parse  it. Or use `nm` and parse it.

Comment: I asked this question about doing this as a part of invoking the GCC linker specifically because I explicitly do not want to write robust post-link build system steps that do this.

Comment: You can probably do something in the linker script. Such as `ASSERT(DEFINED(<symbol>), "Error!")`

Comment: Is it the "robust" part or the "post-link steps" part that you're trying to avoid?  The latter makes perfect sense to me, but the former begs the question of robustness *against what*?  You're already toolchain-specific, so it doesn't seem like portability is your concern.

Comment: How many names are you dealing with?  Can you create a header `deprecated.h`, which is always included in your builds and designates each deprecated function as deprecated (`__attribute__((__deprecated__))` in GCC) so that you get a warning at compile time (which would be converted to an error by `-Werror`).  Or you can compile with `-Werror=deprecated-declarations`, which forces any use of any of the deprecated functions to become an error.

Comment: @EugeneSh. interesting if assert will work with defined as it is evaluated quite early in the linking process .

Comment: @0 I don't have anything to test it right now but I am curious too if it will actually work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question, below is an example that might help. The example code comes from [Hello World for bare metal ARM](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/)

As mentioned above this approach uses `ASSERT ( DEFINED( symbol, "message" ) )`

### Problem

> . . . forbid a set of specifically-named symbols from being linked into my executable . . . Is there a way to achieve this with the GCC linker?

What if the symbols are coming from a static library file `*.a` ?

### Output

In this output the symbol `print_uart0` is the symbol being excluded from an object file `test.o`. Also shown is what happens when the symbols are coming from a static library file `libtest.a`.

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -T test-no-print-uart0.ld test.o startup.o -o test.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: OOPS, THE SYMBOL print_uart0 IS DEFINED

arm-none-eabi-ld -T test-no-print-uart0.ld libtest.a startup.o -o test.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: OOPS, THE SYMBOL print_uart0 IS DEFINED
```

### Process

1. Build inputs into a working ARM example
2. Modify linker script to prevent link when `print_uart0` is included from object file
3. Modify linker command to use static library created from object file

```
# step 1
arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g startup.s -o startup.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g test.c -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -T test.ld test.o startup.o -o test.elf
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel test.bin

Hello World!
# ctrl-a x

# Step 2
arm-none-eabi-ld -T test-no-print-uart0.ld test.o startup.o -o test.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: OOPS, THE SYMBOL print_uart0 IS DEFINED

# Step 3
arm-none-eabi-ar rcs libtest.a test.o 
arm-none-eabi-ld -T test.ld libtest.a startup.o -o test.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: OOPS, THE SYMBOL print_uart0 IS DEFINED
```

### Inputs

#### startup.s

```
.global _Reset
_Reset:
 LDR sp, =stack_top
 BL c_entry
 B .
```

#### test.c

```c
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x101f1000;
 
void print_uart0(const char *s) {
 while(*s != '\0') { /* Loop until end of string */
 *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
 s++; /* Next char */
 }
}
 
void c_entry() {
 print_uart0("Hello world!\n");
}
```

#### test.ld

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x10000;
 .startup . : { startup.o(.text) }
 .text : { *(.text) }
 .data : { *(.data) }
 .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .;
}
```

#### test-no-print-uart0.ld

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x10000;
 .startup . : { startup.o(.text) }
 .text : { *(.text) }
 .data : { *(.data) }
 .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .;
}
ASSERT( !DEFINED(print_uart0), "OOPS, THE SYMBOL print_uart0 IS DEFINED" );
```

Comment: put it into the library and see if it works. Because the object files are easy, libraries not

Comment: Cool. Thanks for testing it. I'll sleep better now :) Library case is also interesting, but I believe it should work too. Just check in the map file which symbols are imported from some library in the same code and put them in the assertion

Comment: @0___________ , understand specifics are more difficult than the simple example above, trying to help, updated the example to use a static library. Always concerned there is a non-obvious place where a symbol can sneak in, seems like the tools try too hard sometimes, hope that makes you smile, have a great day!

Comment: BTW, why would it matter if the symbols are in an object inside a static library, vs simply being directly linked? There are linker behavior differences between linking static libraries (linker "pulls" needed symbols in) and linking objects (user "pushes" objects in), but I don't understand why for this specific question it's interesting if the symbol is in an object vs a lib?

Comment: @CharlesNicholson, well said. I agree this specific solution shows no differences between object and static library. Only providing the static library case to be clear about what was tested to conclude "not significant if you do it THIS way". Any other ways should be investigated, these tools are tricky and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Write an assembly source file with a line of the form `SymbolName:` for each symbol you want to test for. Assemble this file and add its object file to the link after all libraries (and ensure the libraries are listed after other object modules that might be using these symbols).

If the program uses any of the listed symbols, the linker will report a multiply defined symbol error.

Reasoning: If any of the listed symbols is used, the library module that defines it will be linked in. Then, when the new object module is linked in, the symbol will be multiply defined.

If none of the symbols are linked in, this module will be linked in harmlessly; it should not add any space to the program.